# asp:repeater functionality in android

Tags: android, listview, repeater

I am looking for something like the `<asp:repeater>` in android. Is there anything similar?

I need to autogenerate a listview which will be populated from a database, and i thught a repeater would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [here](http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115&aaid=137) ,you can customize that class